# Transform a dataFrame into readable for plotting barchart with plotly express

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have the following messy dataframe. I have a difficult time to modify it to a usable format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q3_3_1': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': -99.0,
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': -99.0,
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': -99.0,
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': -99.0,
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': -99.0,
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': -99.0,
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': -99.0,
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': 'I have not attended a course on entrepreneurship so far.',
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': 'I have not attended a course on entrepreneurship so far.',
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': -99.0},
 'Q3_3_2': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': -99.0,
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': -99.0,
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as elective.',
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': -99.0,
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': -99.0,
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': -99.0,
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': -99.0,
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': -99.0,
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': -99.0,
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as elective.'},
 'Q3_3_3': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': -99.0,
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': 'I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies.',
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': -99.0,
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': -99.0,
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': -99.0},
 'Q3_3_4': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': -99.0,
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': -99.0,
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': -99.0,
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': -99.0,
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': -99.0,
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': 'I am studying in a specific program on entrepreneurship.',
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': -99.0,
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': -99.0,
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': -99.0,
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': -99.0},
 'Q3_3_5': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': -99.0,
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': -99.0,
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': -99.0,
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': -99.0,
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': -99.0,
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': -99.0,
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': -99.0,
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': -99.0,
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': -99.0,
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': -99.0},
 'Type': {'R_2cedWe4sx09CKlb': 'student',
  'R_3smCukGdFbm4i2t': 'nascent',
  'R_3Oj484bqZHepbmT': 'nascent',
  'R_2Wxyhyo1ZtxL0f6': 'student',
  'R_eh84KSBtWy9OWZ3': 'student',
  'R_1pndKdTJ0GC0crY': 'student',
  'R_3MF4nebUAJ130N1': 'student',
  'R_1rrd0yEcpoziBXX': 'nascent',
  'R_3J3ZATf90VmSonA': 'student',
  'R_aaP0vu2FJGdIrNT': 'active'}})
```

I would like to transform it into a readable format to create a barplot with plotly. The format I'm trying to create is the following

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Question': {0: 'Q3_3_1', 1: 'Q3_3_2', 2: 'Q3_3_3', 3: 'Q3_3_4',4:'Q3_3_5'},
 'student': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'nascent': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0},
'active': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4:0}})
```

the plotly command line I want to use is

```
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df1, x='Question', y=['student', 'nascent','active'], barmode='group', title='Final Term')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't understand how you get values in expected `dataframe` - why `student` has to be `{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 0},`, why `nascent` has to be `{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0}`, why `active` has to be `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4:0}`?  I don't see any correlation between original dataframe and expected dataframe. And if there is no correlation then it impossible to convert it.

Comment: how do you get original dataframe? maybe you should change code which generates original dataframe instead of converting it to expected result.

Comment: you can get expected dataframe using also lists like `'Question': ['Q3_3_1', 'Q3_3_2', 'Q3_3_3', 'Q3_3_4', 'Q3_3_5'],` and code can be more readable.

Comment: Hi This is a survey coming out from Qualtrics. The numbers for each column is a count of the number of times students answered for example" I have attended at least one entrepreneurship course as compulsory part of my studies"

Answer (score 0):

- you have not defined the semantics of your data.  It appears that *-99* is effectively *NaN*
- straight forward to reshape

  1. add *Type* to index
  2. `stack()` the questions into index.  Index will now be *row, Type, Question*
  3. test if row is now a dummy row `ne(-99)`
  4. count (actually sum) boolean values
  5. a bit more tidy up
- you can now generate the plot with exactly the line of code you have specified

```
df1 = (
    df.set_index("Type", append=True)
    .stack()
    .ne(-99)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "Question"})
    .groupby(["Type", "Question"])
    .sum()
    .unstack("Type")
    .droplevel(0,1)
    .reset_index()
)

px.bar(df1, x='Question', y=['student', 'nascent','active'], barmode='group', title='Final Term')
```

[image]